# Listing items from a json array with a for loop stops after if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to list out the elements from a json array using a for loop. There are 3 elements that I need to list but the elements in the array repeat several times and I only want each element to be listed once so I have an if statement that will remove the last element appended if the last element appended already exists.

```
for (var i=0, len=data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust.length; i < len; i++) {
    $("#filters").append("<optgroup id="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType+" label="+data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType+">");
    if (data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType===data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i-1].CustomerType) {
        $("#filters:last").remove();
    }
}
```

My problem is that when this executes the loop stops entirely when it hits the if statement and only appends the first element. any help with fixing this or if you have a better way to do this I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stops because you're at index i=0 and you're referencing i-1 (which would be -1). Use the following if:

```
if (i > 0 && data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i].CustomerType===data.OCC_FiltersObj_Cust[i-1].CustomerType) {
```